# String representation for kinds other than *

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I can get string representation of a concrete type by deriving `Typeable` and then doing `show . typeOf`.  However, I can't derive `Typeable` for such types that contain kinds other than `*`.

Are there any general means to print out types containing such kinds?

*Short clarification*:

I mean types such as

```
data FM10 (a::RGB_Channel)
```

where

```
data RGB_Channel = Red | Green | Blue
```

Comment: What code are you trying and what errors do you get? There's `Typeable1`, `Typeable2`, ... `Typeable7` for those types, and automatic derivation works fine for them in GHC 7.4.

Comment: The docs of [`PolyKinds`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html) say something about generalizing to higher-order `Typeable`s, so probably there's a way to use that approach for arbitrary other kinds, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphic typeable [is being worked on](http://hauptwerk.blogspot.com/2012/11/coming-soon-in-ghc-head-poly-kinded.html).  Essentially, what you are currently doing with types of kind `*` will work for all kinds.  Plan is to include this in [GHC 7.8](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/GhcKinds/PolyTypeable)